# variable is not working dynamically with email id

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I am trying to send email to different users at a time. email is sending to the users but name is not working dynamically. name of the first user is sending to all users.
here is my code:

```
foreach ($entertainers as $accept) {

     $entertain = Entertainer::where('mail_soushin',$accept)->first();
     $entertainer= $entertain->name;      

     $this->view('mail.mail101',compact('entertainer','event','user'))->to($accept)->from($admin->mail_soushin,'Dream Master')->subject('【ドリームマスターズ】コンペ募集が開始されました');
     $entertainer = null;

}
```

this is blade code to show the name of user

```
<span>{{$entertainer}}</span>
```

here `$entertainers` is array of emails and `$entertainer` is the name of a particular user. but this `$entertainer` variable is not dynamically updated based on email.

Comment: please explain more .

Comment: $entertainer= $entertain->name;    this should be changed dynamically based on $accept variable. but it is not changing. on view page  first  name of the array is showing every time

Comment: try to use print_r($entertainer) in your view and check in your array that are you getting different names in your array?

Comment: comment your mail code and then put print_f to $entertainer and check weather it's changing in loop as it suppose to or not

Comment: To pass data in view you can use with method. Just try to use
                    ->with([
                        'entertainer' => $entertainer
                    ]); as it is given in the https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail

Comment: it's changing. but in view side only last name is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of `$entertainer` and return it to the view out of the foreach loop

```
foreach ($entertainers as $accept) {

 $entertain = Entertainer::where('mail_soushin',$accept)->first();
 $entertainer[]= $entertain->name;      
}
 $this->view('mail.mail101',compact('entertainer','event','user'))->to($accept)->from($admin->mail_soushin,'Dream Master')->subject('【ドリームマスターズ】コンペ募集が開始されました');
```

Then in view parse `$entertainer` as an array

```
@foreach($entertainer as $e)
{{$e}}
@endforeach
```